# Can't Install ElasticHQ

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently install ElasticSearch and I want to install the plugin ElasticHQ.

So I go into the `elasticsearch-5.4.0/bin` folder and I used the following command :

`plugin -install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ`

And I had this answer :
`plugin : command not found`

So I try this :

`./plugin install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ` and I got the same answer.

Maybe I forgot a step ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

try this from the root directory of your elastic instance:

```
./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ
```

Comment: I had this following error : `Unknown plugin royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ `

Comment: this answer suggests you need to run it as a standalone server: https://github.com/royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ/issues/273#issuecomment-294388819

Comment: Site plugins are not supported in ES 5.x anymore

Answer (score 1):

Support for site plugins, such as HQ, kopf, head, etc, [has been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_plugins.html#_site_plugins_removed) as of ES 5.x.

On the plugin website it's stated that you [have to host ElasticHQ by yourself](https://github.com/royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ#elasticsearch-50)